# OptParser does not return options

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I have this code sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative File.expand_path('../../lib/argosnap', __FILE__)
require 'optparse'

options = {}

opt_parser = OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.banner = "argosnap #{Argosnap::VERSION} ( http://github/atmosx/argosnap )\nUsage: argosnap [OPTIONS]"
  opt.separator  ""
  opt.separator  "     version: dislay version"
  opt.separator  "     install: installs 'config.yml' and launchd script"
  opt.separator  "     balance: check picodollars"
  opt.separator  ""

  opt.on("-v","--version","display version") do |version|
    options[:version] = version
  end

  opt.on("-c","--config [TYPE]", String, "install configuration files") do |config|
    options[:config] = config
  end

  opt.on("-b","--balance","executes 'argosnap' and displayes notifications") do |balance|
    options[:balance] = balance
  end

  opt.on("-h","--help","help") do
    puts opt_parser
  end
end

begin
  opt_parser.parse!
rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption => e
  puts "No such option! Type 'argosnap -h' for help!"
  exit
end

case ARGV[0]
when "version"
  puts Argosnap::VERSION
when "config"
  Argosnap::Install.new.config
when "balance"
  b = Argosnap::Fetch.new.balance
  puts "Current balance (picodollars): #{b}"
else
  puts "Type: 'argosnap -h' for help!"
end
```

My problem is that `options` hash is empty. It's like if it doesn't accept the `options[:var] = var` defined inside the OptParser class. I'd like to use `-v` and `--version` in my program to make it more unix-like.

I'm using `ruby-2.0`.

UPDATE: The way it is the code `works` I've tried changing `when "version"` with `when '-v'` or `when options[:version]` which seemed the best approach to me, but nothing worked.

Comment: Try changing `options[:version] = version` to `options[:version] = true`

Comment: And what my `when 'switch'` should suppose to look like? Tried `when options[:parse]` or `when '-v'` but still nothing. However, `p options[:version]` returns `true` as a value, so it's accepting the argument.

Comment: when you write `case ARGV[0]` you are totally ignoring the opt_parser... `ARGV[0]` is the first word in the command line... the whole point of `opt_parser` is that you _don't_ look at `ARGV`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you write case `ARGV[0]` you are totally ignoring the opt_parser...
`ARGV[0]` is the first word in the command line. The whole point of opt_parser is that you don't look at `ARGV`:

```
if options[:version]
  puts Argosnap::VERSION
elsif options[:config]
  Argosnap::Install.new.config
elsif options[:balance]
  b = Argosnap::Fetch.new.balance
  puts "Current balance (picodollars): #{b}"
else
  puts "Type: 'argosnap -h' for help!"
end
```